# Compass compile wrong with Unicode character

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

Compass compiled everything well if I didn't put a `@charset "UTF-8";` in my root scss, its output like this:

```
@charset "IBM437";
```

my css output still keeps the right Unicode character, just like this:

```
content: "ĐĂNG";
content: "TRẢ LỜI";
```

Its css still work with Chrome and Firefox but fail in IE because it didn't render the Unicode character and the output will completely be wrong if I put `@charset "UTF-8";`

```
content: "─É─éNG";
content: "TRß║ó Lß╗£I";
```

At this time, with just two properties use Unicode characters, I can still modify it but if I have more Unicode characters, it would be a nightmare.
Do I need to modify config.rb?

Answer (score 6):

If You import files with @import, also declare @charset "UTF-8"; in the first line of root file ( for example styles.scss ) - it helped me.

Answer (score 1):

Your source file is encoded using IBM437 instead of UTF-8, so Sass adds an appropriate @charset declaration in your output files. Try to save your files using the UTF-8 charset.

Comment: The problem is when I save with UTF-8 charset, the output just like you can see,it is more strangle than when I save with no charset